# How do I change `Editor: Auto Indent` behavior in Atom?

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, jsx

In general:

1. How do I determine which package determines what indentation is used when I do the `Editor: Auto Indent` command?
2. How do I change that package's indentation behavior?

(And specifically I want jsx closing bracket location to be airbnb default tag-aligned instead of the current prop-aligned.)